# check if Windows Firewall is allowing an Application

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, windows-firewall, windows-defender

***tl;dr*** using Powershell, how do I check if the Windows Firewall is allowing an application?

Using Windows 10, I want to programmatically check if an Application is allowed through the Windows Defender Firewall. Essentially, I want to check the Firewall dialog *Allow apps to communicate through Windows Defender Firewall* using Powershell.

[image: Allowed apps]

For example, given a program `python.exe` installed at `C:\Program Files\Python\python.exe`, how could I check if that application is allowed to communicate to the various networks *Domain*, *Private*, *Public* from a Powershell script ?

Comment: You're looking at combining get-netfirewallrule and get-netfirewallapplicationfilter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385551/how-to-determine-windows-firewall-rules-program-path-using-powershell-get-netfi

Answer (score 0):

I use this one a few years ago:
https://medium.com/@glizzykingdreko/open-a-port-on-windows-firewall-with-a-simple-powershell-script-dc5cc48d013a

Script:

```
    [int]$port = 3777
)

$ruleName = "Allow Port $port"

# Check if the rule already exists
$existingRule = Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $ruleName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($existingRule) {
    Write-Host "Firewall rule '$ruleName' already exists."
} else {
    # Create a new inbound rule for the specified port
    New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $ruleName -Direction Inbound -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -LocalPort $port
    Write-Host "Firewall rule '$ruleName' created."
}
```

Then run the script form the folder: .\scriptname.ps1 -port 5000